# Can Flyway migrate from jar?

Tags: java, postgresql, database-migration, flyway

I have a subproject which is built into a jar file. There is `src/main/resources/db/migration/V1_1__create_table.sql` in the project.

How to run migrate from this jar?

I tried this `./flyway migrate -url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/myproject -user=myproject -password=myproject -locations=classpath:~/src/myproject/target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but I have got the following error:

`Database: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/myproject (PostgreSQL 9.6)
WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:~/src/myproject/target/myprojectn-0/0/1-SNAPSHOT/jar
WARNING: Schema "public" has version 0.0.6, but no migration could be resolved in the configured locations !`

How to run migration from the jar? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to place your jar in the `<flyway-install>/jars` directory and use `-locations=classpath:db/migration`.

See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/#installation

Comment: I tried `./flyway migrate -url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/myproject -user=myproject -password=myproject -locations=classpath:db/migration`, still cannot find migration files in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case migrations were in `BOOT-INF/classes/sql/migrations` folder of the jar file and flyway couldn't find it with `-locations=classpath:sql/migrations`
But it can reach it with full path like `-locations=classpath:BOOT-INF/classes/sql/migrations`